# page width beyound 1250,headless-chromium will push content to out of left side

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

it looks the default browser width is 1250, when my page content is greater than 1250, let's say 1682px.
then the content be pushed out to the left side(1250-1682 = -432px)
what the result is like this

this is test.js. you can run like `node test.js`

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
async function generatePDF(html) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null, 
        args: [
            "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
            "--no-sandbox",
            "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
            // "--start-maximized" ///not working...
        ]
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.emulateMedia("print");
    await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: "load" }); 
    return [page, browser];
}

generatePDF(require("fs").readFileSync("./test.html", { encoding: "utf8" }));
```

and this is the test.html page. i have set the body to `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;` in purpose. it is run fine in normal chrome browser ,but in headless-chromium, it just looks wired.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <style>
      html {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      html {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
      body {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
      #root {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
      .page {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
    </style>
    <style data-styled="true" data-styled-version="5.0.1">
      .eLkIXm {
        touch-action: auto;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -moz-user-drag: none;
        -ms-user-drag: none;
        user-drag: none;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      data-styled.g1[id="sc-AxjAm"] {
        content: "eLkIXm,";
      }
      .eBZmKI {
        position: relative;
        width: 1682px;
        height: 1122px;
        -webkit-transition: width 0s ease-in-out, height 0s ease-in-out;
        transition: width 0s ease-in-out, height 0s ease-in-out;
      }
      .eBZmKI > .bloodLine {
        opacity: 1;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: 0.3cm;
        border: 2px dashed rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
        pointer-events: none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0s ease-in-out, opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
      }
      data-styled.g6[id="sc-AxgMl"] {
        content: "eBZmKI,";
      }
      .wYfhh {
        width: 1682px;
        height: 1122px;
        -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
        -ms-transform-origin: left top;
        transform-origin: left top;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transition: transform 0s ease-in-out;
        transition: transform 0s ease-in-out;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        position: relative;
      }
      .wYfhh .innerPages {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .wYfhh .innerPages .innerpage {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
        transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
      }
      .wYfhh .innerPages .innerpage.spine {
        width: auto;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
        flex: 1;
      }
      .wYfhh .innerPages .innerpage.normal {
        width: 793px;
      }
      data-styled.g7[id="sc-AxheI"] {
        content: "wYfhh,";
      }
      .bojfHH {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-flow: column;
        -ms-flex-flow: column;
        flex-flow: column;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      data-styled.g8[id="sc-Axmtr"] {
        content: "bojfHH,";
      }
      @page {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        size: 21.59999999969397cm 29.599999999577385cm;
      }
      @media print {
        .yGsvL .page {
          background: yellow !important;
          page-break-after: always;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
          width: 21.59999999969397cm;
          height: 29.599999999577385cm;
        }
      }
      data-styled.g12[id="sc-fzpans"] {
        content: "yGsvL,";
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div class="App2">
        <div class="sc-fzpans yGsvL">
          <div class="inner">
            <div class="pages">
              <div
                class="page sc-Axmtr bojfHH"
                data-page-wrapper="6cce5440-643f-11ea-8571-bd85b5033407"
              >
                <div>
                  <div
                    data-page="6cce5440-643f-11ea-8571-bd85b5033407"
                    class="sc-AxgMl eBZmKI"
                  >
                    <div class="sc-AxheI wYfhh">
                      <style></style>
                      <div class="innerPages">
                        <div style="background:red" class="innerpage normal ">
                          <div
                            style="position:absolute;width:400px;height:36px;transform-origin:center center;transform:translate(-50%, -50%)
          translate(292.8794197642793px, 154.53671804170443px) rotate(0deg);opacity:1;z-index:3"
                            data-id="df4dc0e0-6779-11ea-8389-df0a5368605e"
                            class="sc-AxjAm eLkIXm"
                          >
                            <div
                              style="transition:transform 0.3s ease;transform:scale(1, 1) translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2 ,2) translate(50%, 50%);width:100%;height:100%"
                            >
                              <div
                                style="width:200px;height:18px;transform:translate(0px,0px)"
                              >
                                <div
                                  class="ql-container ql-disabled"
                                  style="width:200px"
                                >
                                  <div class="ql-editor">
                                    <p>
                                      <strong style="color: rgb(255, 145, 77);"
                                        ><em>Hello Kent</em></strong
                                      >
                                    </p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div
                            style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;transform-origin:center center;transform:translate(-50%, -50%)
          translate(591.6930073406838px, 972.4326909016465px) rotate(0deg);opacity:1;z-index:4"
                            data-id="df4e3610-6779-11ea-8389-df0a5368605e"
                            class="sc-AxjAm eLkIXm"
                          >
                            <div
                              style="transition:transform 0.3s ease;transform:scale(1, 1) translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1 ,1) translate(50%, 50%);width:100%;height:100%"
                            >
                              <div
                                style="width:200px;height:200px;transform:translate(0px,0px)"
                              >
                                <div
                                  style="width:100%;height:100%;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center"
                                >
                                  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
                                    <g>
                                      <g
                                        transform="translate(100,90)"
                                        class="slices"
                                      >
                                        <path
                                          class="innerSlice"
                                          d="M -36.2 2.963645253936595e-15 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 1 -36.2 2.963645253936595e-15 L -36.2 20.000000000000004 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 0 -36.2 20.000000000000004 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(40, 79, 159);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="innerSlice"
                                          d="M -36.2 2.963645253936595e-15 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 1 -36.2 2.963645253936595e-15 L -36.2 20.000000000000004 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 0 -36.2 20.000000000000004 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(171, 44, 14);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="innerSlice"
                                          d="M -36.2 2.963645253936595e-15 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 1 -29.2864151963731 -14.22440310547785 L -29.2864151963731 5.775596894522151 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 0 -36.2 20.000000000000004 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(199, 119, 0);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="innerSlice"
                                          d="M -29.2864151963731 -14.22440310547785 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 1 11.18641519637309 -23.01556769434272 L 11.18641519637309 -3.015567694342721 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 0 -29.2864151963731 5.775596894522151 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(12, 117, 19);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="innerSlice"
                                          d="M 11.18641519637309 -23.01556769434272 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 1 36.2 -5.92729050787319e-15 L 36.2 19.999999999999993 A 36.2 24.200000000000003 0 0 0 11.18641519637309 -3.015567694342721 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(119, 0, 119);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="topSlice"
                                          d="M 90 0 A 90 60 0 0 1 27.81152949374527 57.06339097770921 L 11.124611797498108 22.825356391083687 A 36 24 0 0 0 36 0 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(51, 102, 204); stroke: rgb(51, 102, 204);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="topSlice"
                                          d="M 27.81152949374527 57.06339097770921 A 90 60 0 0 1 -72.81152949374525 35.267115137548394 L -29.124611797498105 14.106846055019359 A 36 24 0 0 0 11.124611797498108 22.825356391083687 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(220, 57, 18); stroke: rgb(220, 57, 18);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="topSlice"
                                          d="M -72.81152949374525 35.267115137548394 A 90 60 0 0 1 -72.81152949374527 -35.26711513754838 L -29.12461179749811 -14.106846055019354 A 36 24 0 0 0 -29.124611797498105 14.106846055019359 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(255, 153, 0); stroke: rgb(255, 153, 0);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="topSlice"
                                          d="M -72.81152949374527 -35.26711513754838 A 90 60 0 0 1 27.81152949374525 -57.06339097770922 L 11.124611797498101 -22.825356391083687 A 36 24 0 0 0 -29.12461179749811 -14.106846055019354 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(16, 150, 24); stroke: rgb(16, 150, 24);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="topSlice"
                                          d="M 27.81152949374525 -57.06339097770922 A 90 60 0 0 1 90 -1.469576158976824e-14 L 36 -5.8783046359072966e-15 A 36 24 0 0 0 11.124611797498101 -22.825356391083687 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(153, 0, 153); stroke: rgb(153, 0, 153);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="outerSlice"
                                          d="M 89.5 20 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 1 27.657020996557797 76.58786271956163 L 27.657020996557797 56.587862719561635 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 0 89.5 0 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(40, 79, 159);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="outerSlice"
                                          d="M 27.657020996557797 76.58786271956163 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 1 -72.40702099655779 54.973222511402156 L -72.40702099655779 34.973222511402156 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 0 27.657020996557797 56.587862719561635 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(171, 44, 14);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="outerSlice"
                                          d="M -72.40702099655779 54.973222511402156 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 1 -89.5 20.000000000000007 L -89.5 7.286648454926752e-15 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 0 -72.40702099655779 34.973222511402156 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(199, 119, 0);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="outerSlice"
                                          d="M -89.5 20.000000000000007 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 1 -89.5 20.000000000000007 L -89.5 7.286648454926752e-15 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 0 -89.5 7.286648454926752e-15 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(12, 117, 19);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <path
                                          class="outerSlice"
                                          d="M -89.5 20.000000000000007 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 1 -89.5 20.000000000000007 L -89.5 7.286648454926752e-15 A 89.5 59.5 0 0 0 -89.5 7.286648454926752e-15 z"
                                          style="fill: rgb(119, 0, 119);"
                                        ></path>
                                        <text
                                          class="percent"
                                          x="43.686917696247164"
                                          y="21.160269082529034"
                                        >
                                          20%
                                        </text>
                                        <text
                                          class="percent"
                                          x="-16.686917696247157"
                                          y="34.23803458662553"
                                        >
                                          20%
                                        </text>
                                        <text
                                          class="percent"
                                          x="-54"
                                          y="4.408728476930472e-15"
                                        >
                                          20%
                                        </text>
                                        <text
                                          class="percent"
                                          x="-16.686917696247168"
                                          y="-34.238034586625524"
                                        >
                                          20%
                                        </text>
                                        <text
                                          class="percent"
                                          x="43.68691769624716"
                                          y="-21.16026908252904"
                                        >
                                          20%
                                        </text>
                                      </g>
                                    </g>
                                  </svg>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div
                            style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;transform-origin:99.99999999999989px 100.00000000000006px;transform:translate(-99.99999999999989px, -100.00000000000006px)
          translate(660.4914814143247px, 232.23934968268364px) rotate(-15.522360738375369deg);opacity:1;z-index:2"
                            data-id="df4e8430-6779-11ea-8389-df0a5368605e"
                            class="sc-AxjAm eLkIXm"
                          >
                            <div
                              style="transition:transform 0.3s ease;transform:scale(-1, 1) translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1 ,1) translate(50%, 50%);width:100%;height:100%"
                            >
                              <div
                                style="width:200px;height:200px;transform:translate(0px,0px)"
                              >
                                <img
                                  src="https://ss3.bdstatic.com/70cFv8Sh_Q1YnxGkpoWK1HF6hhy/it/u=2905486894,2646015843&amp;fm=26&amp;gp=0.jpg"
                                  style="object-fit:fill;width:100%;height:100%"
                                  draggable="false"
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div
                            style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px;transform-origin:center center;transform:translate(-50%, -50%)
          translate(210.71576053578224px, 968.900242739742px) rotate(0deg);opacity:1;z-index:11"
                            data-id="df4eab40-6779-11ea-8389-df0a5368605e"
                            class="sc-AxjAm eLkIXm"
                          >
                            <div
                              style="transition:transform 0.3s ease;transform:scale(1, 1) translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1 ,1) translate(50%, 50%);width:100%;height:100%"
                            >
                              <div
                                style="width:400px;height:400px;transform:translate(-100px,-100px)"
                              >
                                <img
                                  src="https://ss3.bdstatic.com/70cFv8Sh_Q1YnxGkpoWK1HF6hhy/it/u=2905486894,2646015843&amp;fm=26&amp;gp=0.jpg"
                                  style="object-fit:fill;width:100%;height:100%"
                                  draggable="false"
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div
                            style="position:absolute;width:450px;height:300px;transform-origin:225.0000000000001px 150px;transform:translate(-225.0000000000001px, -150px)
          translate(332.63271441523125px, 567.6116192203082px) rotate(0.1700476276704208deg);opacity:1;z-index:0"
                            data-id="df4ed250-6779-11ea-8389-df0a5368605e"
                            class="sc-AxjAm eLkIXm"
                          >
                            <div
                              style="transition:transform 0.3s ease;transform:scale(-1, 1) translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1 ,1) translate(50%, 50%);width:100%;height:100%"
                            >
                              <div
                                style="width:450px;height:300px;transform:translate(0px,0px)"
                              >
                                <img
                                  src="https://t8.baidu.com/it/u=1484500186,1503043093&amp;fm=79&amp;app=86&amp;size=h300&amp;n=0&amp;g=4n&amp;f=jpeg?sec=1580734170&amp;t=9f62c4e350e667c8a67aa2c0d97f56e8"
                                  style="object-fit:fill;width:100%;height:100%"
                                  draggable="false"
                                />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div
                          style="background:red"
                          class="innerpage spine "
                        ></div>
                        <div
                          style="background:red"
                          class="innerpage normal "
                        ></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

## final updated

after i lunch putteteer with `devtools: true`,i finaly got why that happen
there is a css define that effect the page layout. i removed it,and it looks fine now.

```
@media print {
        .yGsvL .page {
          background: yellow !important;
          page-break-after: always;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
          width: 21.59999999969397cm;
          height: 29.599999999577385cm;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the args in the puppeteer configuration is the size of the window, even if it is headless...

This will do the trick to define the size

```
args: [`--window-size=1920,1080`]
```

Or even:

```
launchPuppeteerOptions: {
    args: [`--window-size=1920,1080`],
    defaultViewport: null
}
```

Comment: thx,use that argument the default window size is bigger,however,the content still keep out of left side. when i try to open the dev tools, the content just jump back to normal,so hard to figure out why that happen